# C#: WinForm Container Focus Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, controls, focus

I'm making a Windows Form as seen below. When I click on a row in the `DataGridView`, the details of a person is transferred unto the `TextBoxes` at the side. When the user click the `Edit` button,the *entire* `Panel` *to the right* becomes editable; the `TextBoxes` and `CheckBoxes` are `Enabled` and allows the users to edit a person's name, birthday, etc. After which, the changes are saved to the database.
[image]
I don't want the user to click a different row while editing and thus want to detect when a user leaves the `Panel` so I can prompt him/her.

How do I detect if I've lost focus of the `Panel`? 
If I'm going about this wrong, please respond with the appropriate answer instead.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to make what should be a modal dialog box and flatten it into the main form.  You should probably re-think your gui interface.

Comment: What is a modal dialogbox and how do I make one?

Comment: "modal dialogbox" googles pretty well.

Comment: Oh, I do that for other interfaces. I chose Panel for this because it also serves a viewing purpose. Not all data in the Panel can be seen in the DGV.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when the user begins editing a record in the `Panel` you could set the `Enabled` property of the DataGridView to `False`, and when a `Save` button is pressed you can set the `Enabled` property to `True` again.

Comment: I decided against that because if I wanted to add more controls in the future that deals with the DGV, then I'd have to handle them one by one too. An example would be the Filter. I can still filter the DGV even if it's disabled.

Comment: @DonovanKeating Instead, you could disable the DataGridView in the DataGridView MouseEnter event, if the user has not yet saved in the panel. You can then re-enable in in the MouseLeave event, or if the panel is saved.

Comment: Isn't that just like what your post suggests?